# mysql changes the IP when connecting

Tags: mysql

could you please help me

I exec

```
mysql -h 192.168.100.16
```

And get such response

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'192.168.100.171' (using password: NO)
```

As you can see there is different ip in response. Why is this happening?
I can ping both of the ips and there are no problems with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are connecting *to* `192.168.100.16`, and the server is rejecting the connection *from* `192.168.100.171`. The solution is to configure the server to allow connections *from* that IP address, for that user, with no password. (Or connect from another IP address, use a different user name, or specify a password.)